# Moving files between Windows computers without creating network shares

Tags: .net, windows-server-2008-r2

### What's needed:

To move several directories between two Windows 2008 servers on a regular basis.

Due to security requirements, neither server is supposed to have network shares set up or extraneous software installed.

### What's available:

Administrator access to both machines (including remote desktop access if that helps).

A third machine with:

- Visual Studio 2010
- Cygwin

### Bonus extras

The script that does the rest of the work (apart from moving the files) is currently written in F#, but any .net/command line based solution would be fine.

Comment: Have the servers had their hidden shares (C$, etc.) removed?

Comment: What about default shares? e.g., \\server1\\D$

Comment: "Due to security requirements", you should create regular user accounts to move the files and use that instead of the administrator accounts and default/hidden shares...  Of course this will require network shares to be set up, but that's the whole point of them.  Network shares allow you to limit the directories the users have access to, etc.  I didn't put this as an answer because I went against your security requirements, but really, this is the most secure.

Comment: Depending on your requirements, the other thing that could be done (but your administrators would have to be involved), is to set up replication/DFS.

Comment: "neither server is supposed to have network shares set up or extraneous software installed"... really, with these two requirements, you might as well not connect them to the network.  Use USB drives to transfer from one to the other...  I'm done ranting. :)

Comment: @Nelson Note the 'extraneous'. The servers already have Dynamics CRM installed, they're just not file shares.

Comment: Hidden shares it is: I'd forgotten to check for them on the servers as our personal machines have them disabled, but they are there. I'd mark grenades answer as accepted except that he left it as a comment!

Comment: mavnn: Right, Dynamics CRM would need to be on the network.  I meant it in the context of transferring files.  Anyway, a custom share is still a better idea, but if the default shares are available and you can use them, it'll get the job done.

Comment: Nelson: don't worry, I've had my own rants about 'security' requirements before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) to be a useful tool to achieve this.

Comment: Yes, that may help.  It does install "extraneous software" (a PsExec service), but from what I understand is temporary and gets cleaned up.

Comment: PsExec works by copying itself onto one of the server's hidden shares. You might as well use the hidden C$ share directly.

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple file-transfer program from the ground up with .NET Sockets? That's what I would do at least. Just byte-stream over the network with a few preset folders that can only be reached using this program (that both would need async IO).

Edit: Or maybe this counts as extraneous software, no matter how small?

Answer (score 0):

You can zip your directories up and send them across via [netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to LZMA/RAR/ZIP it up and use scp (ssh/ssl ftp) or mount and unmount ssh file systems (sshfs, should be possible with cygwin). However, if this is more secure than SMB shares is another question. The pro of mounting and unmounting sshfs file systems is, the share is only available until the data has been transmitted, and it's protected by a 4096 bit private-public RSA key, and not a lumpy password.

Comment: The Windows 2008 servers don't have cygwin.  He can't install any software on the servers.  I really don't see how this (or almost anything, really), can be done.